# How can I store the object in the database

Tags: c#, serialization

I have the `Sock` data object and I want to store this object into the database; so I could retrieve it later; is this possible?

I know in Java I can implement `Serializable`, what about c# ?

Comment: http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=94

Comment: Serialization is a programming technique and not specific to any language. So far as you implement the realizable interface, you can easily do it. However, if your object consists of unmanaged resources such as connection to database etc, you might not be able to do so. In either case, you are to decide how to serialize the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). It will do most of the job for you. And it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ADO.NET to store this object. You can reference here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners